# How can I convert type dynamically in runtime in Golang?

Tags: reflection, go, runtime

Here is my example:
http://play.golang.org/p/D608cYqtO5

Basically I want to do this:

```
theType := reflect.TypeOf(anInterfaceValue)
theConvertedValue := anInterfaceValue.(theType)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation

```
value.(type)
```

is called a [type-assertion](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions). The `type` in an assertion has to be known at compile-time and it's always a type name.

In your playground example `SetStruct2` could use a [type-switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) to handle different types for its second argument:

```
switch v := value.(type) {
case Config:
    // code that uses v as a Config
case int:
    // code that uses v as an int
}
```

You cannot, however, assert an interface to be something dynamic (like in your code). Because otherwise the compiler could not type-check your program.

Edit:

> I don't want to case them one by one if there is another way to do so?

You can use [reflection](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to work type-agnostically. You can then set stuff randomly on values but it will panic if you perform an illegal operation for a type.

If you want to benefit from the compiler's type checks you'll have to enumerate the different cases.

Comment: The purpose of doing this kind of thing `value.(type)` is
I might have many struct like `Config1` ... `Config100`, I don't want to `case` them one by one if there is another way to do so.

Comment: If you just want to check the type, or assert it to use it, you can just do `val, ok := value.(TypeICareAbout)`. This can be fairly useful for doing things like checking what kind of error an error "actually" is, if it implements a package specific interface, so that you can use behavior it exposes (i.e. http://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/24/inspecting-errors).